# Python - Flask BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: KeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I keep getting the following error:

**BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'customer_account_number'**

Where am I going wrong? I am using Python 2.7 running Flask.

Here is my python script:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

template_dir = os.path.abspath('c:/users/ned06')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_dir)

@app.route('/')
def quiz():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/account_number', methods=['POST'])
def quiz_answers():
    customer_account_number = request.form["customer_account_number"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and here is my HTML:

```
 <form action="/account_number" method="POST">
    <p>Input Customer Account Number</p>
    <input name="customer_account_number" </input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input name="customer_account_number" </input>
```

YOu are missing closing bracket here.

Comment: I tried this:  <input name="customer_account_number"> </input>   and still get the error...

Comment: It should be `<input name="customer_account_number">`, without the closing tag.